# windows 10 icons set

Tags: icon, windows

Didn't expected to get stuck with it, however it is seems to be a problem.

Is there any publicly available standard icons set for windows 10 applications design? (Something like here for material https://material.io/icons/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the release of Windows 10, the **Segoe MDL2 Assets** font replaced the Windows 8/8.1 Segoe UI Symbol icon font.

How to copy an icon:

- Press Windows key + R (Run), type `charmap` and hit Enter.
- Select the **Segoe MDL2 Assets** font from the drop-down menu then look for the icon you want to use and copy it (via the Select and Copy buttons).
- You can search an icon with the unicode from Advanced view option within charmap.

  [image: charmap]

You can find the unicodes at this link:
[Segoe MDL2 icons](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font)

---

**Guidelines:**

[Icons for UWP apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/icons)

[Guidelines for tile and icon assets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets)

Answer (score 0):

Its FREE for commercial and personal use Download [here](http://graphicdesignjunction.com/2015/07/windows-10-icons/)

[image]

After click the Download button new page open

[image]

Click on download zip