# What are the Windows 10 top bar icon guidelines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, windows

Long story short, I'm building an app that doesn't have the official Windows 10 minimize, maximize and close buttons.

So I want to add them by hand. Now I searched a bit on the net but couldn't find what the standard distances/sizes are for these buttons.

I found this:
[image]

and this:[image]

I'm curious what the official guidelines are. I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb226827(v=vs.85).aspx) from Microsoft but that's clearly outdated.

Thanks!

Edit: No my question is not the same as [this one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/100748/windows-10-icons-set). I'm asking about guidelines, which is not answered in that question

Comment: Hi! I already answer a similar question about W10 icons here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/100748/windows-10-icons-set/100753#100753 . Read my answer and make sure to check the links. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if the icons in that pack are the same as used in that top bar?

Comment: Most likely yes. :)

Comment: No it isn't. I'm asking about guidelines, not an icon set

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find documentation or design guidelines for the top bar in Windows 10.
But the Windows Dev Center provides [layout templates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/downloads/index) for different design software (Photoshop, Illustrator, Sketch, XD, Framer).

Somewhere in there you'll find the specs I'm sure.